# VLC Player and VirtualBox font problem in Xubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, virtualbox, fonts, vlc

I've installed VLC player and VirtualBox. Both of them have the similar character/font problem as you may see from the screen shots.

I also tried to install and re-installing them via Software Center and also tried to install them from terminal (after removing each of them completely).

I'm having trouble with just that two and I did not tried to install extra font package previously.

For VLC screen shot ==> https://i.stack.imgur.com/sG6j1.jpg

For VirtualBox screen shot ==> https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4fkL.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my problems by using ***Infinality***. While looking any kind of cure to my problem, I've noticed Infinality and installed it with the following from terminal.

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:no1wantdthisname/ppa
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get upgrade
>
> sudo apt-get install fontconfig-infinality

After that, I've installed VLC and VirtualBox from synaptic and both worked fine ;)

Hope it may help anyone who needs.

Best